# Add Windows 10 IoT Core to a Domain

Tags: active-directory, iot, windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT Core. Does anybody know if its possible to add this flavour of OS to a standard Active Directory domain?... And if so, how please?

I appreciate that this wouldn't be a typical use case for such a device, but we are just playing around in the office and I'm trying to make life easier to authenticate against the device.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?  It's driving me mad!

Comment: @Oliver not yet :-(

Comment: In my case it was for windows auth on a browser.  For now I've enabled anonymous auth on the required display pages - not ideal!

Comment: Any solution? I would be interested in the same question for rolling out updates on many PI devices.

Answer (score 0):

We just assigned it an IP, then set that as the IP in the Pi.

For example:

Do as outlined here to add as trusted host, http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm

Then, assuming your IP was 10.10.0.1,

set-executionpolicy remotesigned
import-module NetTCPIP
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" –IPAddress 10.10.0.1 -AddressFamily IPv4 –PrefixLength 16 -DefaultGateway 10.10.0.2

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Underground however I'm not worried about DHCP. I'd like the device on the domain specifically for the purpose of authentication. Etc; getting to the UNC path of the local storage without entering additional credentials.

Comment: Looks like IOT Enterprise supports this, but core is not listed. https://sec.ch9.ms/sessions/winhec/slides/04-2015ShenzhenWinHECFallWorkshopKeynote-CreateyourIndustrydevicewithWindows10IoT.pdf